# RFC 2253 - Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (v3)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, rfc, distinguishedname

I'm using the following: https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/jldap/jldapenu/api/com/novell/ldap/util/DN.html in my application.

For the creation of the DN object, I need to put dnString, that must adhere to the syntax described in RFC 2253.

My DN contains: "\" and "," characters (also "\," both right after each other).

I could not find any site that explains exactly how to get a valid DN for RFC 2253. I found:

https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/RFC%202253

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc2253.txt.pdf

Both mention that "," and "\" are special characters, but none states how to escape it correctly.

How can I get the valid DN with these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 4 of [RFC 2253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc2253.txt.pdf):

> If a character to be escaped is one of the list shown above, then it is prefixed by a backslash (’\’ ASCII 92).

So an escaped comma should be `\,` and an escaped backslash should be `\\`.

A comma is a separator in a DN. For example:

```
cn=admin,ou=marketing,o=corporation
```

so it needs to be escaped only when it is *not* used as a separator, like this:

```
cn=Smith\, John,ou=marketing,o=corporation
```

Active Directory will escape it for you if you create an object with a CN that has a comma.

The backslash is a special character because it's used to escape other characters. So if you are *not* using it for that purpose, it needs to be escaped using itself:

```
cn=North\\South America,ou=marketing,o=corporation
```

Although in that example I'd use a forward slash ("North/South America"), which brings up another point (unrelated to your immediate problem, but worth mentioning): the forward slash is not a special character in DNs, but they are in LDAP paths. So if you had a DN like this:

```
cn=North/South America,ou=marketing,o=corporation
```

Then if you need to use that in an LDAP path, you can't just drop that in:

```
LDAP://cn=North/South America,ou=marketing,o=corporation
```

because `/` is a separator character, so it would think that the DN is just `cn=North`. In those cases, you need to escape that with a backslash too:

```
LDAP://cn=North\/South America,ou=marketing,o=corporation
```

But *only* when you use it in an LDAP path.

Comment: So if I have `CN=Chik\, Chak` it should go as `CN=Chik\\\, Chak`?

Comment: That depends. If the `cn` attribute is "Chik, Chak", then it should appear as `CN=Chik\, Chak` in the DN. If this is Active Directory, then you can just look at the `distinguishedName` attribute. However it shows there is how you should be using it.

Comment: I'm using Softerra LDAP browser. The `distinguishedName` attribute goes: `CN=Chik\, Chak,OU=..` and there are some more OU and DC, with no special characters or spaces. And yet the novell library still throw the IllegalArgumentException

Comment: It's a bit of a problem. I'm using the following portal - https://github.com/OpenUnison/openunison-k8s-login-activedirectory. When I look at the OpenUnison pod's logs, I see:`Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

        at com.novell.ldap.util.DN.<init>(DN.java:440)`

Comment: Here is [the source code at line 440](https://github.com/aptivate/openldap-jldap/blob/master/com/novell/ldap/util/DN.java#L440) of DN.java. Although I don't quite understand what it's complaining about.

Comment: Are you giving it the DN value? If so, are you giving it the complete DN (everything you see in the `distinguishedName` attribute)?